# Can I round-trip an aligned pointer through an IEEE double?

Tags: c, ieee-754

Can I round trip any 4-byte-aligned pointer through a double?  And can I round trip any finite double through a string?

Specifically, on any platform that uses IEEE floating point, which conforms to C11, and on which neither static assertion fails, are the assertions in the following program guaranteed to pass?

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
   struct {
      void *dummy;
   } main_struct;
   main_struct.dummy = 0;
   static_assert(_Alignof(main_struct) >= 4,
                 "Dummy struct insufficiently aligned");
   static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t) && sizeof(double) == 8,
                 "double and uint64_t must have size 8");
   double x;
   uint64_t ptr = (uint64_t)&main_struct;
   assert((ptr & 3) == 0);
   ptr >>= 2;
   memcpy(&x, &ptr, 8);
   assert(!isnan(x));
   assert(isfinite(x));
   assert(x > 0);
   char buf[1000];
   snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "Double is %#.20g\n", x);
   double q;
   sscanf(buf, "Double is %lg\n", &q);
   assert(q == x);
   assert(memcmp(&q, &ptr, 8) == 0);
}
```

Comment: The real question is perhaps, why wouldn't you just use a `union` instead?

Comment: @Dolda2000: because a union can't do the shift, which is required to avoid Nan values, which would otherwise cause problems.

Comment: While you're probably fine on "ordinary" platforms, I have to question the wisdom of any system within which you find it natural and reasonable to represent pointers as "non-NaN doubles". :)

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour for violating effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. It does not even come to the dynamic assertions. Also `uint64_t` is not guaranteed to hold a pointer - why not use the type meant for this: `uintptr_t`? Arithmetics on such a pointer value is not defined either, nor what happens if such a value is cast back to a pointer. The question is: what is your **actual** problem you try to solve? As @Dolda2000 wrote: why not use a `union`, although that still would not solve all problems.

Comment: @Dolda2000 My situation is that I need to push an arbitrary aligned pointer onto LuaJIT's internal stack, so that I have access to it from a callback (passed to `lua_cpcall` in case you were wondering).  I can't use a Lua lightuserdata because on LuaJIT it only supports pointers in the bottom 47 bits of the address space, which breaks on AArch64.

Comment: @Olaf Would you mind explicitly stating why strict aliasing is violated?  `memcpy` is specifically blessed to allow it to copy memory from any C object to any other C object.

Comment: @Demi: In such a constrained situation, it doesn't seem you'd have reason to care about strict C11 compatibility, at least. It doesn't sound like the surrounding Lua code is strictly C11-compliant, to say the least. :) I don't know nearly enough about Lua's internals to give concrete advice, but if you can store arbitrary doubles, then surely it must be possible to store arbitrary pointers, too?

Comment: @Demi: That does not matter. You are not allowed to use `memcpy` just to circumvent the effective type rule. Just read 6.5p6 ff.

Comment: @Dolda LuaJIT stores _everything_ as a double, using NaNs for all other values, but there are not enough values reserved for opaque pointers.  So I need to pack a pointer into a double.

Comment: @Demi: Are you actually expecting the result of this to be portable and well-defined according to the standard? If so, I would perhaps argue that you may need to re-examine that expectation. :) If not, why are you caring about what the standard says about portable programs?

Comment: @Dolda I guess I care if it will work with real compilers on real platforms, and will not be broken by future compiler changes.

Comment: @Demi: Personally, I'd argue that it sounds like LuaJIT is already out there in hack-land if it stuffs pointers into NaN values, so as long as you play by those rules, you should probably not expect the most robust results in terms of portability and well-definedness, and the *real* solution sounds like fixing LuaJIT at the root. That being said, however, I personally can't think of any reason on any "popular" platform that would prevent your trick.

Comment: @Dolda LuaJIT is all about performance.  While this trick is hackish, it is also compact and fast.

Comment: @Demi: I realize that, but I don't think it changes any of the points I made. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Specifically, on any platform that uses IEEE floating point, which conforms to C11, and on which neither static assertion fails, are the assertions in the following program guaranteed to pass?

With only those requirements, then no. Among reasons that preclude it are the following:

- You haven't asserted that pointers are 64 bits or less in size.
- Nothing says that pointers and doubles use the same kind of endianness in memory. If pointers are big-endian and doubles are little-endian (or middle-endian, or use some other weird in-memory format), then your shifting does not preclude negative, infinite or NaN values.
- Pointers are not guaranteed to translate simply into an integral value with lower-order bits guaranteed to be zero just because they point to an aligned value.

These objections may be somewhat pathological on current, practical platforms, but could certainly be true in theory, and nothing in your list of requirements stands against them.

It is, for instance, perfectly *possible* to imagine an architecture with a separate floating-point coprocessor that uses a different memory format than the main integer CPU. In fact, the Wikipedia article actually [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point) that there are real examples of architectures that do this. As for weird pointer formats, the C FAQ provides some [interesting historical examples](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: If it's using IEEE format floating points (as stated in thw question), then it is safe to assume that the format of the double in memory conforms to the IEEE standard. I think, on x86_64, he is going to be OK but nothing about C11 guarantees that (your bullet points are probably only a few of the issues).

Comment: @JeremyP: The IEEE standard only speaks of the format of the entire loaded 64-bit word, but it doesn't specify how to store that word in memory. Certainly, BE and LE machines store them differently even today.

Comment: But it's probably a reasonable assumption that a little endian machine will store floating points little endian.

Comment: @JeremyP: See my edit for counterexamples. :) But yes, while it is a reasonable assumption, C11 alone does not guarantee it.